# Vue-cli, build script - need single app.js file, but get many chunk files ( splitChunks set to false, no dynamic imports )

Tags: vue.js, webpack

For current project I need single `app.js` file.

But after running build script folder `dist/js` contains many chunk files:

```
npm run build
```

[image]

My `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  filenameHashing: false,

  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],

  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I'm not using any dynamic imports - no structures like `import(...)`.

Comment: Try using `webpack-chain` to configure code splitting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370432/9556193

Comment: Tried, same result